# How many threads does curl_multi_exec use?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I'm using `curl_multi_exec` in php to check the status of a number of URLs. I want to benchmark this so that, for a given system, I know how many handlers I can check synchronously before curl starts queuing. Does anyone have any experience on how to gauge capacity?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You could use `netstat` and watch the number of active connections it opens.  Then increase the the number of urls until you notice the count from netstat start to fall off...

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but most urls will return in less than, say, half a second. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Well, create a site on the same server (or another local).  Create a page that just sleeps for 60 seconds or so.  Then open a ton of connections to that page.  That should be long enough for you to get meaningful output from `netstat` yet still be easy and quick to build...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from PHP source code that it uses select() and non-blocking reads.
So only one process is used.

Note that select() will fail, if you give it a file descriptor with fd >= FD_SETSIZE. The FD_SETSIZE limit is defined when compiling PHP. The default seems to be 256. It would be better to use poll() in the PHP implementation.

**About correct curl_multi_exec() usage:**

curl_multi_exec() should be followed by curl_multi_select(). That will wait for available data, instead of checking them in a busy loop.
The [example in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) is good.